# Find index of last slash(/) in a string in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `Laravel` and I used `getModel()` method on `ModelNotFoundException` object:

```
$modelName = $exception->getModel();
```

**I Want:**
To extract "User" from the $modelName.

**My code:**

```
$modelName = $exception->getModel();
$pos =strrpos($modelName,'/');
$modelName = substr($modelName, $pos);
```

**Output:** 
`App\\User` .

How to get only the `User` part of the `$modelName`?

**Restriction**: can use `strrpos()` **PHP function** only .

Comment: Sounds like homework, which is fine. But can you show us what you have tried to code so far please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `strrpos` returns `false` and therefore `substr` starts from the start.

Model namespaces use `\`, not `/`. You have to use `strrpos($modelName,'\\');`. Double `\` is there otherwise `'` would get screened off. Hence, you need to screen the back slash itself.

```
$pos =strrpos($modelName,'\\');
$modelName = substr($modelName, $pos);
```

Now this will return `\User`. In case you do not need the first slash, you can go with

```
$modelName = substr($modelName, ++$pos);
```

Comment: without ++ it should return \User BUT it returns \\User. Why?

Comment: @AK `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`... Maybe your output is configured to escape the back slash

Answer (score 2):

You want to find the last "\" char in the input so you are searching for "/"?

There's your first error.

The next issue is that the "\" character is the escape character, so be careful how you quote it.

But you want everything **after** the character - so your substring should start one character to the right.

```
$pos =strrpos($modelName,'\\');
$modelName = substr($modelName, $pos+1);
```